# Overlapping a font awesome icon inside a text field

Tags: css, overlay, font-awesome

In an overlapping like the one below, how to prevent the large space between the title and text field?

```css
.icon-link-mail {
  position: relative;
  left: 485px;
  top: 29px;
  padding: 8px 8px 7px 8px;
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<h3>Title</h3>
<form name="mail_form" id="mail_form" method="POST" action="">
  <label for="sendto">
              <a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-2x icon-link-mail" style="color:#E4E4E4; text-decoration:none"></i></a>
              <input name="sendto" class="sendto" type="text" style="width: 98%; margin-bottom:10px" placeholder="Send to.." />
              </label>
</form>
```

Result can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ay6Hw/)

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your explanation. Is it the gap between the title and the text field that's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I'd just use a pseudo-element, but if you wish to use the `<i>` icon, then we can do that a lot better by using `position:absolute` instead of `position:relative`. Adding `position:relative` just moves the icon, but leaves the space that it would have taken. `position:absolute` won't leave that space.

We need to make sure to set the parent contain (label) to `position:relative` though, so that the icon will be absolutely positioned in relation to the parent instead of the entire page.

```css
#mail_form label {
  position: relative;
}

.icon-link-mail {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Title</h3>
<form name="mail_form" id="mail_form" method="POST" action="">
  <label for="sendto">
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-2x icon-link-mail" style="color:#E4E4E4; text-decoration:none"></i></a>
        <input name="sendto" class="sendto" type="text" style="width: 98%; margin-bottom:10px" placeholder="Send to.." />
     </label>
</form>
```

Result

[image]

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ay6Hw/4/

Comment: When running into problems with your positioned element overlapping other relative or absolute positioned elements, set its z-index to -1.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to do this is to just use an image.  Here would be the code:

```
.search input {
padding-left: 17px;
background: #FFF url("../images/icon_search.png") left no-repeat;
}
.search input:focus {
background:#fff;
}
```

This will also remove the background image on focus giving the user a better experience overall.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I must first consider an alternative that uses a font awesome icon!

Comment: Ok, you could always use the :before or :after psuedo to get it working using only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works with simple CSS and standard font awesome syntax, no need for unicode values, etc.

1. Create an `<input>` tag followed by a standard `<i>` tag with the icon you need.
2. Use relative positioning together with a higher layer order (z-index) and move the icon over and on top of the input field.
3. (Optional) You can make the icon active, to perhaps submit the data, via standard JS.

See the three code snippets below for the HTML / CSS / JS.

Or the same in JSFiddle here:
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ethanpil/ws1g27y3/

```js
$('#filtersubmit').click(function() {
  alert('Searching for ' + $('#filter').val());
});
```

```css
#filtersubmit {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -25px;
  top: 1px;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
<i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search"></i>
```